# Where is info about scheduling sleep/awake device for iOS 6.0 and above?

Tags: ios, ios6, power-management

I can get this info from the file  **/private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist**
for 3.x - 5.x firmwares, according hint from http://code.google.com/p/iphone-insomnia/

Where can i find this info for ios 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS only have background/suspend/active/inactive/not-open state.

Normally, an App operates either in suspend/active state. You can request background process time with API and a separate handler function.

More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's not an answer. Just a piece of information which you may found interesting.

I grepped the binary and I found only mentioning of com.apple.AutoWake.xml (which should be accessible at the same directory).

The mentioning were in 
/System/Library/CoreServices/powerd.bundle/powerd
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation